# Why does this document grow horizontally with position: absolute and transform: translate?

Tags: html, css

I've a menu that's being used in a PhoneGap app, thus targeting webkit, and I've noticed that the [following code(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/KLzK6/2/) grows the document horizontally.
But if I swap out so it's `position: relative;` or `position: fixed;` it works as I expect it to. I.e. the document doesn't grow.

From what I understand `position: absolute` shouldn't take up space in the document, or am I understanding [this explanation of it wrong?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values)

CSS:

```
#navigation {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="navigation"></div>
```

[image: Screenshot of jsfiddle where the document width has grown]

Comment: `position: absolute` removes the element from the document flow, but content WITHIN that element still behave normally.

Comment: Aaah, am I understanding it correctly like this: 

Being taken out of the flow means that other elements can occupy the space that was set aside for #navigation. #navigation still affects the document/viewport (which would be the correct term for this?) as it has a width/height, just that the positioning is separate to the other elements?

position: relative already got it's space in the document and moves around separately so that would be why? And position: fixed is the same as in the position is set and when translate is used it still occupies the same space, but is not visible?

Comment: it's kind of like you printed the page out on magic paper. When you cut out an element with the absolute positioning, it's like you physically took scissors and chopped it out of the magic paper, which then heals the hole by moving "lower" areas to fill in the gap.

Comment: Mm, I understand that part. I was confused about how the positioning affected the rest of the document. But I noticed that the behavior of `translate`, in this instance, is the same as doing `right: -100%` so I'm just confused of how absolute and positioning worked. Thanks for the help! :)